# A Row of Cells Contain Pass and FAIL Need a Formula to Determine True Pass or Fail

Tags: excel

I have row of cells that contain PASS or FAIL (as the text value) I can't seem to figure out the formula that would state IF FAIL shows up 3 times then add Fail to A new Cell, ELSE Pass.  Any help would be great.

I've tried several IF IF(OR and COUNTIF formulas but cannot get it quite rite.

Essentially in a new cell it will say either PASS or FAIL once the criteria is met.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use:

```
=IF(COUNTIF(B2:Z2,"FAIL")>=3,"FAIL","PASS")
```

Comment: @UselessITGuy Please consider marking as correct by clicking the check mark by the answer.